# XML Tables not showing in Chrome or Safari

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML tables on the following page do not show up, not even an error message, in Chrome or Safari:

http://www.desertrealestate.com/news.htm

The tables are at the bottom of the page. I've wracked my brains for a month now and haven't been able to find a solution.

The first xml file is at: http://www.desertrealestate.com/xml/mCitiesSFR.xml and the corresponding xsl file is the same with extension xsl.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need UniversalRead for displaying a web page? Feels a borderline malicious to me.

Comment: that code was written automatically by MS Expression Web. I'm not a programmer!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what control you are using but if you investigate the page source you will see the following:

```
<!-- PlaceHolderPreview MSDataViewXMLSrc="xml/mCitiesCT.xml" MSDataViewXSLSrc="xml/mCitiesCT.xsl"  -->
<iframe onload="FP_xslview(this, /*url*/'xml/mCitiesCT.xml', /*url*/'xml/mCitiesCT.xsl', 'Unsupported browser. Use Windows® Internet Explorer® 7, Internet Explorer 6, or Mozilla Firefox 1.5.')" style="display: none">
                    </iframe>
```

I'm not aware of what the MSDataView control is but it clearly states that only Internet Explorer and Firefox are supported.

```
'Unsupported browser. Use Windows® Internet Explorer® 7, Internet Explorer 6, or Mozilla Firefox 1.5.'
```

Comment: O.K., I was able to get one table to render using the following code, but how do I get a second table to render on the same page? It keeps saying argument is a duplicate?

Comment: it's too big for this. you can see it at desertrealestate.com/news.php.

Comment: What keeps saying the argument is a duplicate? If you need to add more code that won't fit in a comment you can edit your question with updated information.